# How can i replace a value in a specific row and column in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to replace a value in correspondence of an ID in a .csv file:

```
ChatId,Color
805525230,black
```

So if the ID in input is equal to the one in the file my program will replace the Color "black" with the new one. I tried this:

```py
for idx, row in enumerate(df.ChatId):
    if str(row) == str(CHAT_ID):
        df.loc[1,idx] = BGc
        df.to_csv("path")
```

Comment: What do you want to replace the value `black` with?

Comment: With BGc input, like white for example

Comment: What do you mean by BGc?

Comment: Did you try: `df.Color[df[df.ChatId] == 805525230 ]= 'White'` ?

Comment: A variable that contains a new color taken as an input

Comment: Try: `df.Color[df[df.ChatId] == 805525230 ]= ' #BGc# '`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you loaded the csv on a dataframe, you could you use some of its functions.

For example: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Alternatively, you could use the loc function:

```
df.loc[df['ChatId'=='SomeId'], 'Color'] = 'ValueToReplace'
```

If you need to apply it to a different column, you can 'Color' with the appropriate name. 
I think you could even include a list of column names, though I haven't tested it

Comment: I solved it by using **df.at**: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html). Thank for the help anyway!